# vba call: value display without pressing play button

Tags: excel, vba

why I have to press run button every time to run every vba code. Example I would like to sum `a1+b1`, result show in `C1`. Then `a2+b2` result shows in  `C2`.

But this code not run automatically. I have to click play button every time. Is there any way so that when I put value in `A1` or `B1` result shows in `C1` without pressing macro button or play button (in VBA Editor).

I want to just run it like excel formula

Comment: Make it a UDF or put the code in Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: If you explain little that will be really helpfull for me..

Comment: Google will be able to help you with this much better than we can.  I gave you two keywords that should get you started.  It is hard to be more specific when you yourself are vague.  Look up those two keywords try them and when you get stuck, come back with the code you have tried and explain specifically what is going wrong.

Comment: @ scott.thank you so much.I am Able to find out my solution with the help, of your code..thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You must put your code inside the `Worksheet_change` event of your worksheet, and do not forget to disable Application events, otherwise it is infinite loop:

```
private sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
       '
       ' call your update procedure
       '
    Application.EnableEvents = True
end sub
```

Use VBA Editor on the worksheet you want:

[image]